# Undefined References Static Library DS-5

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, static-libraries

I'm trying to get the LAME mp3 encoder running on an ARM processor. I've written a simple test code to initialise and close the encoder to test that I've set up the environment correctly but I can't build the project successfully. I've cross compiled the source lame code for arm linux (successfully?) using the arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc toolchain. I used the following configuration to build the static library:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/root/gcc-linaro-arm/bin
echo $PATH
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
export LD=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
export AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
export NM=arm-linux-gnueabihf-nm
export RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib


./configure CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --prefix=/root/x-compile/deps --
enable-static --disable-shared --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
make
make install
```

There were some warnings but as far as I can tell it was built correctly. However, when I build my project in the DS-5 environment that uses functions defined in the static library, the linker is unsuccessful. I'll post a snippet below:

```
Invoking: GCC C Linker 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L/root/DS-5-Workspace/mp3codec/shared_lib -o 
"mp3codec"  ./src/mp3codec.o   -lmp3lame
/root/DS-5-Workspace/mp3codec/shared_lib/libmp3lame.a(vbrquantize.o): In 
function `guess_scalefac_x34':
vbrquantize.c:(.text+0xa68): undefined reference to `__log10f_finite'
/root/DS-5-Workspace/mp3codec/shared_lib/libmp3lame.a(lame.o): In 
function `lame_init_params':
lame.c:(.text+0xdce): undefined reference to `cos'
lame.c:(.text+0x1026): undefined reference to `cos'
lame.c:(.text+0x10f0): undefined reference to `cos'
lame.c:(.text+0x110c): undefined reference to `cos'
makefile:31: recipe for target 'mp3codec' failed
lame.c:(.text+0x1214): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'
lame.c:(.text+0x12f4): undefined reference to `__powf_finite'
/root/DS-5-Workspace/mp3codec/shared_lib/libmp3lame.a(psymodel.o): In 
function `init_s3_values':
psymodel.c:(.text+0x5ac): undefined reference to `__exp_finite'
```

It goes on and on about undefined references in various files in the static library. I've read a bit and it seems an issue could be how the linker is called, but that is done by the IDE when I tell it to build, so I'm not sure if its out of my hands. I'm also unsure if the static library for lame is built correctly. I've tried building it from the terminal as above, and also using the source files in DS-5. I've gotten a static library object out both ways, but the same issue regarding undefined references when I try to build the project that is dependant on static library.

Can anyone give me insight into my issue, or tell me the steps to correct them?

Thanks for any help,

Bogdan

Comment: Have you checked you added all the dependent files?

Comment: I'd assume they're all there. The library I'm using right now was built using the configuration files that came with the lame project. I've built the project using the Linux GCC toolchain in DS-5 and got the expected console output. For some reason I can't figure out, when I try to use the ARM toolchain for the static library I get this issue. I've also tried using a shared library to build. It builds, but the code exits with status 127 "Command not found" so I'm sure its the same issue with undefined references.

Comment: Did you try adding `-lm` to the linker arguments to link against math lib?

Comment: I haven't. Do you pass math as an argument with -lm? Also, if this is in regards to the linker in the Eclipse IDE, I'm not sure how to pass additional arguments, since all I know how to do is select the option to build project. Do I have to edit the makefile? It suggests you don't.